# nullity of nxn matrices being transformed by trace

Tags: linear-algebra

$T:M_{nxn} (F) \to F$ via $T(A)=tr(A)$. Recall that $$tr(A)=\sum^{n}_{i=1} A_{ii}$$

Find the nullity without the dimension theorem.

---

So, in an n by n matrix there are n entries on the diagonal. so we have $nn-n$ so far and then i get confused as how to get it to $nn-1$.
Or maybe there is a better way.

*anyways appreciate constructive input of course*

---

*question is part of a bigger problem here it is if needed*

prove $T$ is linear transformation and find bases for both $N(T)$ and $R(T)$. Then compute the nullity and rank of $T$ and verify the dimension theorem. Finally, use the appropriate theorems to determine whether $T$ is one-to-one or onto

$T:M_{nxn} (F) \to F$ via $T(A)=tr(A)$. Recall that $tr(A)=\sum^{n}_{i=1} A_{ii} $

Let $A,B \in M_{nxn} (F)$. So, $T(A)= \sum ^n _{i=1} A_{ii} $, $T(B)= \sum ^n _{i=1} B_{ii}$.

Now $$T(A+B)=\sum^n _{i=1} A_{ii}+B_{ii}=
\sum^n _{i=1} A_{ii}+ \sum^n _{i=1}B_{ii}= T(A)+T(B)$$

let $c\in F$ so  $ T(cA)=\sum^n _{i=1} cA_{ii} = c \sum^n _{i=1} A_{ii}=cT(A)$

*Should not be using the Dimeansion theorem here just verifying but*
$$\begin{aligned}
Dim(M_{nxn})=nn&=Rank(T)+Nullity(T)
\\&=1+Nullity(T)
\end{aligned}$$
$Null(T)=nn-1$. Not 1-1; not maps to F entirely. that is for the case $n>1$ it would be trivial,redundent  to say n=1 but just in case. Nullspace would be only 0 so it is 1-2-1 and it is onto.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the trace is in fact a linear functional, and as any other non-zero functional, its kernel is a maximal subspace of the domain. With this you already get $\;\dim\ker T=n^2-1\;$ , as maximal subspaces
 of finite dimensional spaces always have dimension one less than the whole space.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $dim \ker T$ is $n^2-1$ Indeed $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ii}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

You can exhibit a basis of the kernel: consider all matrices of the form $A_{ij}$ where all coefficients are zero, except for $1$ at place $(i,j)$. This is a basis for $M_{n\times n}(F)$ (easy check), which therefore has dimension $n^2$.

Consider then
$$
\{A_{ij}:1\le i,j\le n, i\ne j\}\cup\{A_{ii}-A_{nn}:1\le i<n\}
$$
This set has $n(n-1)+(n-1)=n^2-1$ elements and is linearly independent (easy check). Every matrix in this set belongs to the kernel of $T$. Since $\ker T$ is a proper subspace, because $A_{11}\notin\ker T$, we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Is the $ker T$ for this function identified with the set of non-invertible $(n \times n)$-matrices?